# Deploy .net build files from one windows server to another windows server which is in AWS

Tags: asp.net, windows, jenkins

I have two windows server 01 and 02. 02 is created in AWS and it has IIS where my site is hosted . Using Jenkins I am trying to push the build files from 01 to 02 . But I am unable to do it . Publish using CIFS plugin is not allowed by Admin team .

Appreciate your suggestions .

Comment: I don't see any code to help you with.

Comment: I am sorry . I have mentioned about deployment where configuration steps are involved rather than code.